# Invoke upi payment app from website and get payment status

Tags: php, html, ionic-framework, payment-gateway, upi

create an HTML page which have some buttons to invoke popular UPI payments apps like Google Pay, Paytm, PhonePe, etc.
Pay Now !

I am able to invoke upi application but now want to know how to know the success of the transaction

I am able to invoke the application using url.

Now trying to get the payment transaction status

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For UPI, you can check the status of the transaction using the following Transaction Status Check API.: `check_upi_txn_status`

Pass the following parameters

```
key: merchant key
command: name of web service
hash: sha512(key|command|var1|salt)
var1: transaction details in json format
```

The response contains

```
status
message
result
```

For further details, please check the official documentation:

https://devguide.payu.in/upi/upi-api-reference/check-upi-transaction-status-api/#Request